# Putty fatal error Disconnected: no supported authentication methods available.

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, amazon-web-services, putty, ssh-keys

I am connecting to a Ubuntu server via Putty and keep getting "Disconnected: no supported authentication methods available. Server refused our key." I am able to connect as ubuntu (superuser) but not as any other user. I am using Amazon web services if that helps.

Comment: Is your public key in the `.ssh/authorized_keys` files for the other users?

Comment: Ah thanks for the input! I'll get back to you

Comment: Yes, I have placed the public key in the .ssh/authorized_keys file using the 'vi' command and inserting the pub. key on a new line. I might just create another user and start over. Is there a straight forward article/resource anyone could recommend?

Comment: I don't have an article to recommend, but you might check log files in `/var/log` and see if there are any better diagnostics from the SSH server.

Answer (score 2):

Amazon actually has a guide for setting up Putty on Windows to connect to your AWS instances.  It even details WinSCP for secure transfer of files.  Pretty helpful guide.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/putty.html

Answer (score 1):

Permissions on the files in .ssh need to be restricted as well. Manpage has something on this. Also try with the logging in putty up and let us see the error from client. Also check server side /var/logs messages or syslog file.

Answer (score 0):

Look like sshd server does not accept **ssh-dss** public key for authentication.
Just add to /etc/ssh/sshd_config key **PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes** and add value **ssh-dss**

```
PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes ssh-ed25519,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com
```

to see what public keys are supported on server:

```
ssh -Q key
```